# Unable to delete a directory from vmware?

Tags: linux, rm

I am trying to delete a file in hortonbox sandbox setup on my vmware workstation player 12 and I am getting continuous error "invalid argument".

```
rm -rf 1
rm: cannot remove `1': Invalid argument
```

Right now I am at `/var/run/ambari-server/stack-recommendations` trying with user root.

Edit: 1 is the directory name I am trying to delete and I had tried it in single and double quote as well. Error does not change.

Comment: And 1 is what, a directory in that directory?

Comment: 1 is the directory name i am trying to delete.

Comment: What has "ls -al ./1" to say?

Comment: `total 8
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 18 00:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 16 05:42 ..`

Comment: Very strange. Did you try "rm -rf ./1" ?

Comment: Still the same error. I am on vmware sandbox machine. Does that matter?

Comment: I dont know. If I had a really good idea, I would have told you.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank You so much for your help. I wish someone helps me out!!! Badly need it as of now. :)

Comment: Well, if it just had helped. I was seriously expecting to see many answers by now.

Comment: Me too. Let's hope I get some soon. :(

Comment: Can you try running `rm -rf -- ./1`? `--` signifies the end of options and means that the directory name won't be interpreted by the command as an option.

Comment: It didn't helped. However the main issue related to ambari is solved.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/62271/unable-to-add-apache-nifi-in-ambari.html) to Hortonworks forum thread. That version of the sandbox was broken:

> This is due to a docker issue in this 2.5 sandbox build. It will be
>   fixed in next revision of the sandbox.

Updated sandbox available for downloading now at http://hortonworks.com/downloads  and everything works fine there