# Can not delete file due to “Invalid argument”

Tags: linux, files, directory, rm

I got this weird error when I try to delete some file. And the filename doesn't contain any specific characters. Does anyone know why ? It is centos

```
[root@sandbox ~]# rm -rf /var/log/zookeeper
rm: cannot remove `/var/log/zookeeper': Invalid argument
```

Comment: Can you write to the file and try to delete it again? Like echo "foobar" > /var/log/zookeeper  (http://brattex.blogspot.de/2012/07/invalid-argument-when-trying-to-delete.html?m=1)

Comment: Actually this is a empty folder.

Comment: I see.. Maybe this one? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317130/unable-to-delete-a-directory-from-vmware.

Comment: There may be something special about the directory. Post the output of `ls -la zookeeper`.

Comment: Use `rmdir` to remove empty directories.

Comment: use `getenforce` to see if you are running selinux. If so, run `ls -Z` to check the security descriptors the problem directory. Try using `setenforce 0; rmdir /var/log/zookeeper;setenforce 1`. use `ls / /var /var/log` to see if the containing directories have appropriate execute permissions.  Use `mount` to check whether any of these directories are mountpoints that might be mounted in RO mode. try rm'ing as root using `sudo` or `su`.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar happened to me when I was trying to remove an empty folder from a remote server.
This is what `ls -al` was giving as output:

```
??????????   ? ?       ?       ? ? latest
```

This was a folder inside another folder and I wanted to delete this.
I tried `rmdir` and this is what I got:

```
rm: cannot remove: latest: Invalid argument
```

Nothing seemed to work directly on that folder(not `rm -f`, not `touch`, nothing). However, I tried renaming the parent folder and the `latest` folder was normal again, which I was then able to delete using `rm`.

Comment: here in WLS for a folder called 14593, in Windows this folder cannot be removed and parents can't change name, be deleted, nothing:

    "ls -la ." gives ->
    
    "d????????? ? ?     ?       ?            ? 14593" but not even changing the name i could deleted